# Why is passport.authenticate needed in a registration?

Tags: passport.js

I'm learning Passport, using local strategy and Mongoose, through passport-local-mongoose plugin.

It makes sense to me in a /login for example, but I don't understand why passport.authenticate is needed in a registration, right after it having already taken place...

Can anyone explain me, please? Also, what if it fails?

The following code was taken from a tutorial, but I have found similar constructions all over.

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({ username : req.body.username }),
      req.body.password, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({err: err});
        }
        if (req.body.firstname) {
          user.firstname = req.body.firstname;
        }
        if (req.body.lastname) {
          user.lastname = req.body.lastname;
        }
        user.save(function(err,user) {
          passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
              return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration Successful!'});
          });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password isn't used to authenticated the user inside this snipped.

1. Call User.register

   Creates a new User Object with the username, and needs the password to do 
    some magic with it. Probably build a hash which gets added to your 'user' object.
2. Call user.save

   Saves this 'user' object inside your Storage, if this is successful the user gets authenticated, and returns HTTP 200 which ends the registration process. 
   Error Handling isn't implemented in this save method, for that you will have an exception on error.

Hope this helps to understand, your snippet.

To use your /login method your new user can use his username and password which he gave to you during the registration process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't understand if passport.authenticate is really needed or not

Comment: this depends what you are going to do with this new created user, should he see special content after he got created, or has access to a special area. then the authentication is useful. With this step you just sign the user into his new account/session.

Comment: ok, so it is as I suspected.. it's not really needed in a registration if I will keep registration and login as separate endpoints